# Configure each taskbar in Windows 10 multi-monitor setting?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, taskbar

Is there a way to configure **each** taskbar in Windows 10? Maybe at least not to show date and time at the secondary taskbar (at the bottom right)? I want the secondary taskbar looks different (so kinda remind me that is the secondary monitor).

In office, the computer I previous used was Windows 7 with two monitors. I used [Dual Monitor Taskbar](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dualmonitortb/?source=navbar) so that there was a taskbar in the secondary monitor. The Dual Monitor Taskbar appearance is difference from the Windows taskbar. (It has an option to show or hide 'Start' button in secondary taskbar. And it does not show date and time in secondary taskbar.)

Now I have a new computer. Windows 10. Same two monitors. The only thing I can make secondary taskbar looks different is to select 'Taskbar where window is open' for 'Show taskbar buttons on'.

Information: windows 10 Pro, build 14393.

Comment: Yes, you can make it look different, but not by much. If you want more control, you will need software.